# Ipython display function html equivalent but for r kernel

Tags: html, r, ipython, width, display

I have the following code in an ipython cell (python kernel):

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

With this, when I export to html, the notebook take full width of the html.

Is there any equivalent but for an r kernel ipython notebook?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to make that when exporting the notebook to html, it takes the total width. I modified the file .../anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nbconvert/resources/style.min.css adding `.container {
  width:100% !important;}`